# Is a robust `Function.prototype.bind` polyfill possible?

Tags: javascript

In conjunction with `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call`, `Function.prototype.bind` is used by Node.js to preserve "primordial" prototype methods in a form usable by its internal library and unaffected by any mutations to builtins by user code. This is the relevant section from [`primordials.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/0a62026f32d513a8a5d9ed857481df5f5fa18e8b/lib/internal/per_context/primordials.js):

```
// `uncurryThis` is equivalent to `func => Function.prototype.call.bind(func)`.
// It is using `bind.bind(call)` to avoid using `Function.prototype.bind`
// and `Function.prototype.call` after it may have been mutated by users.
const { apply, bind, call } = Function.prototype;
const uncurryThis = bind.bind(call);
primordials.uncurryThis = uncurryThis;

// `applyBind` is equivalent to `func => Function.prototype.apply.bind(func)`.
// It is using `bind.bind(apply)` to avoid using `Function.prototype.bind`
// and `Function.prototype.apply` after it may have been mutated by users.
const applyBind = bind.bind(apply);
primordials.applyBind = applyBind;
```

All that is needed to save `Array` for internal library use is to assign it to a variable scoped to the internal libraries. Saving `Array.prototype.push` for reuse is trickier because it normally has to be a property of an object to work. `uncurryThis(Array.prototype.push)` produces a function whose first parameter is the `this` value that gets used by `Array.prototype.push`, which is now usable even if user code deletes the method from the prototype of `Array`.

Unlike `apply` and `call`, `bind` is unavailable in older JavaScript engines, so it cannot be used to save preserve builtin methods. P"Bound" functions returned by polyfills for `Function.prototype.bind` that I have encountered thus far are written a way that is susceptible to breaking if, for instance, `apply` and `call` were deleted from `Function.prototype`.

Is there some way to polyfill `Function.prototype.bind` in such a way that functions returned by it cannot be broken by monkey patching?

Comment: How old of a JavaScript engine are we talking here?

Comment: _"Bound" functions returned by polyfills for Function.prototype.bind that I have encountered thus far are written a way that is susceptible to breaking if, for instance, apply and call were deleted from Function.prototype._ - this doesn't matter, all that usually matters is that `call` and `apply` haven't been deleted **yet** by the time the polyfill runs.

Comment: I guess you can write a function that does `call.call = call; call.call(fn, thisArg, …)`. If monkey patching can break it, you can fix it.

Comment: You can sort of do it by enforcing `Function.prototype.call.call === Function.prototype.call`, but that’s a terrible idea and can still be broken by user code or break user code (`Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype.call, 'call', { configurable: false, … })`). I don’t think it’s possible otherwise – functions can’t be cloned pre-`bind`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The [standard polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/ce52fdc735c5c809c9e85b2072f92d41b5a3885a/packages/core-js/internals/function-bind.js#L23) *does* access and call `.call` from within the bound function

Comment: @Ry- I guess we can safely assume that the engine is old enough not to support `Object.definedProperty`, so that can't break it

Comment: @Bergi: As long as it doesn’t support `__defineSetter__` either…

Comment: @Ry- At first I would have suggested to `__lookupGetter__`, remove it and restore it afterwards… but of course those could have been overwritten as well and we can't `call` them for circular reasons. However, `if (call.call !== call) { delete call.call; call.call = call; }` should do, you cannot (could not) intercept/prevent `delete`. Well, maybe you need to check for (and restore) the correct prototype chain as well… hm…

Comment: @Bergi: Have to do that unconditionally to avoid a getter that returns the correct `call` once :D And it messes with more environment than before. Restoring the environment seems impossible if `__lookupGetter__` can be overwritten, or even just if the call leads to a user-defined function being called that relies on the user environment. Are we allowed to give up and call it an XY problem yet? :P

Comment: @Ry- Yup, I give up (but boldly claim I can break anything an answerer could come up with) :D

Comment: @Bergi Old enough to not have `Function.prototype.bind`.

Comment: @Ry- XY problems don't exist.

Comment: @Melab: That’s quite wrong. I encourage you to blog about it instead of pinging me three years later though